# How to set the DOCKER_HOST env variable on a MAC

Tags: macos, docker, environment-variables

I am trying to run a program on Mac that needs a docker daemon access to run. For this I set the `DOCKER_HOST` env variable that the program can use in the following way

```
setenv DOCKER_HOST "tcp://<ip-of-docker-daemon-host>:2375"
```

But the program detects it as an http address. I also tried the following

```
setenv DOCKER_HOST "http://<ip-of-docker-daemon-host>:2375"
setenv DOCKER_HOST tcp://<ip-of-docker-daemon-host>:2375
```

But still get the same error. I also restarted the docker daemon making sure it it making itself available on port 2375 as follows

```
sudo docker -H 0.0.0.0:2375 -d &
```

I am on Mac OX Capitan 10.11.5

Answer (score 0):

maybe unix socket approach will help

```
docker run -ti -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock centos bash
```

?

Comment: what do I set the DOCKER_HOST variable to connect to the daemon?

Comment: I've just assumed that you want gain the access from one container to rule another containers like like is described here https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy